# Grails app: How to set Display Name for tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails

In pre Gails 3 times, I was able to change the display name in `web.xml` in order to show up under the respective column in tomcat manager.

I've already tried this inside `application.yml`, but without success:

```
server.display-name: '@info.app.name@ - @info.app.version@'
```

How is this being done in Grails 3?

Comment: With which version of Grails 3 did you try that?  I haven't verified that it works but https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2600 seems relevant.

Comment: from `gradle.properties`: `grailsVersion=3.2.3
gradleWrapperVersion=3.0`